# Two identical messages are received at the same time as push notifications through FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Vue.js and FCM to implement WebPush notification. However when I test it, I receive one notification from the Firebase and TWO IDENTICAL PUSH NOTIFICATIONS that are received by the client regardless of browser or device.

Please any help will be highly appreciated!

The following is the excerpt of the JS.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

function showNotification(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var title = data.notification.title;
    var tag = 'push';

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        icon: data.notification.icon,
        body: data.notification.body,
        data: data.data,
        vibrate: [400,100,400],
        tag: tag
    });
}

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

function receivePush(event) {

    console.log("receivePush");
    console.log(event.data.json());
    if(event.data) {
        data = event.data.json();
    }
    if('showNotification' in self.registration) {
        event.waitUntil(showNotification(data));
    }
}

function notificationClick(event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url)
    );
    addClickCount(event.notification.data.record_id);
}

function addClickCount (record_id) {
    var api_url = 'https://' + location.host + '/_app/api/auth/push';
    fetch(api_url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({id: record_id}),
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text));
}

self.addEventListener('push', receivePush, false);
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', notificationClick, false);
```

The following is the excerpt of the token.

```
<template>
        <div class="column-btn">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="btn btn-white">
              <a
                href="javascript:void(0);"
                class="btnItem push-yes"
                style="background:none"
                >Yes</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="btn btn-white">
              <a
                href="javascript:void(0);"
                class="btnItem push-no"
                style="background:none"
                >No</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
</template>

export default {
  methods: {
  },
  mounted() {
    var pData = this.$parent;
    var thisData = this;
    $(document).on('click', '.push-yes', function() {
      pData.permission_off();
      thisData.modalClose();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.push-no', function() {
      thisData.modalClose();
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are clear steps in FCM what code to add to Service Worker firebase-messaging-sw.js (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive):

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

I've implemented as written there and it's working just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
    icon: data.notification.icon,
    body: data.notification.body,
    // data: data.data,   <--- REMOVE THAT LINE 
    vibrate: [400,100,400],
    tag: tag
});
```

And if you're in backgroundMessage remove the line self.registration.showNotification for not send the notification twice

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages